# Passing a parameter through output binding AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, binding

I'm having to following setup with AngularJs 1.5.8, using Typescript:

I have a parent component which contains a catalog (2D array of items). From where I pass each list in the catalog to a child component:

```
...
export class ParentController {

    private catalog = []; //contains a list of lists

    ...

    private printCallback(item: any): void {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in $ctrl.catalog">
    <child content="list" callback="$ctrl.printCallback(item)"></child>
</div>
```

Now in the child component I iterate again over every item in the list. And whenever I click on an item from the list, I want the parent to know the item I clicked on:

```
export class ChildComponent implements IComponentOptions {
template: any = require('./child.component.html');
public bindings: any = {
    content: '<',
    callback: '&'
};
controller: any = ChildController;
}

export class ChildController {

    public content: Array<any>;
    public callback;

    ...

    public onTrigger(item: any): void {
        this.callback(item);
    }
}
```

And the child template:

```
<div ng-repeat"item in $ctrl.content">
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.onTrigger(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
</div>
```

Now I can't seem to print the **item** in the **printCallBack()** of my parent component. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong cause the only thing that's printing is *undefined*.
I've looked around and couldn't find a working solution. So I hope you can help me.

Comment: try `this.callback({item : item});`, while calling.

Comment: @anoop Well that just made my day. I knew it was in the details, but I couldn't lay my finger on it. You gonna make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While callback, do it like: `this.callback({item : item});`, pass as object.